Google Sheet read always timeout
I use the following code to read google sheet ,Recently at certain times of the day, and this operation always timeout and it used to work normally
public List<List<Object>> getSpreadsheetValue(String spreadsheetId, String dataRange) {
        List<List<Object>> values = null;
        try {
            ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, dataRange)
                    .execute();
            values = response.getValues();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("read google sheet failed ,{}", e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return values;
    }

error message:
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:978)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)

I tried to set the timeout to 5 minutes but it still return timeout.  But if I create a new table and copy the data from this table to the new table, it can work normally without timeout.  Also, the range of the table I read is very small and there are no formulas. Has anyone encountered the same problem that can help me  thanks

How heavy is the spreadsheet?

About 200 rows and 20 columns, but I only read one row, and each cell has only one number

How many sheets/tabs in spreadsheet file?

But if I create a new table and copy the data from this table to the new table, it can work normally without timeout. So, why not just use a new copy of the spreadsheet? Sometimes too many revisions(edits saved in revision history) may cause issues.

The maximum of around 20, and the minimum of only two, all experienced timeouts

So, why not just use a new copy of the spreadsheet? Sometimes too many revisions(edits saved in revision history) may cause issues.
Is this possible to cause this problem？Because there are other tables referencing the data in this table, only this table will be updated

Too many IMPORT* formulas "may" cause this issue.

This spreadsheet does not reference any other sheet, but others have referenced it. Could this be the reason

Not sure... If you're only "read"ing, but not "writing" to the spreadsheet, I don't think it should matter... So, I'm not sure what issue is with your spreadsheet. In any case, see https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/troubleshoot-api-errors#sheet You can create a issue in the tracker, if the above troubleshooting tips didn't help: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#developer_product_feedback PS: Make sure your internet connection or ISP is not the cause. Try changing to a different ISP

Thank you for your suggestion. It was very helpful. I will try
